# Is there a way to find sum of specific column in pyqt5 QtTableWidget ? and show it by specific row

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I want to find sum of columns(FMV, Charges, Initial Payment, Final payment and Dew balance)
as in screen shot and show these values in respective row i.e. Total. and i don't want to save the total row in the database.

```
`def show_banking_view_page(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.bank_view_page)
        conn = sqlite3.connect("sm.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * from Banking"
        result = conn.execute(query)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, 
                      QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
            
        conn.commit()
         conn.close()`
```

here is the screen shot....
https://i.stack.imgur.com/89N36.png